# MySQL regex function Turkish character problem

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am searching with php in Turkish. In Turkish alphabet have 'i' and 'ı' lowercase characters. Also have 'I' and 'İ' uppercase characters.

Mysql select query in regex function cannot be found Turkish character, example: İ - ı .. My search column data type character set UTF-8 general_ci.

I am waiting for your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a known problem

Comment: What version?  Before MySQL 8.0, regexps were not good with multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the Turkish character problem in the following ways.

Use the HTML and JQuery code, like below;

```js
function searchBarReplaceChar() {
        searchInput = $.trim($('input[name="replaceChar"]').val());

        let charMap = {
            Ç: '[CÇ]+',
            C: '[CÇ]+',
            Ö: '[OÖ]+',
            O: '[OÖ]+',
            Ş: '[SŞ]+',
            S: '[SŞ]+',
            İ: '[Iİ]+',
            I: '[Iİ]+',
            Ü: '[UÜ]+',
            U: '[UÜ]+',
            Ğ: '[GĞ]+',
            G: '[GĞ]+',
            ç: '[cç]+',
            c: '[cç]+',
            ö: '[oö]+',
            o: '[oö]+',
            ş: '[sş]+',
            s: '[sş]+',
            ı: '[ıi]+',
            i: '[ıi]+',
            ü: '[uü]+',
            u: '[uü]+',
            ğ: '[gğ]+',
            g: '[gğ]+',
        };

        let str_array = searchInput.split('');

        for (let i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++) {
            str_array[i] = charMap[str_array[i]] || str_array[i];
        }

        searchInput = str_array.join('');

        let replaceChar = searchInput.replace(/[]/gi, "");
        let lastChar = replaceChar.slice(-1);
        if (lastChar === '+') {
            replaceChar = replaceChar.slice(0, -1);
        }
        $('.result').text(replaceChar);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="replaceChar" value="şehir bu gece çok güzel" />
<p class="result"></p>
<button type="submit" onclick="searchBarReplaceChar()" >Send</button>
```

send this result to your php file with ajax post.

later, your php file code,

```
public function search_regexp() {
    $regexp = str_replace('i', 'İ', $_POST['get_replace_result']);
    $regexp = str_replace('ı', 'I', $regexp);
    $regexp = mb_strtoupper($regexp, "UTF-8");
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE example_column regexp '$regexp'";
    // $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE example_column regexp '[SŞ]+EH[Iİ]+R B[UÜ]+ [GĞ]+E[CÇ]+E [CÇ]+[OÖ]+K [GĞ]+[UÜ]+ZEL'";
}
```

do not forget this, mysql database in your table column data type character set `utf8_turkish_ci`

Good luck with

Answer (score 0):

With `COLLATION utf8_turkish_ci` (or utf8mb4), and only with that, MySQL treats

```
I=ı  <  İ=i=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=î=ï=Ĩ=ĩ=Ī=ī=Ĭ=ĭ=Į=į
```

The rest of the accented letters are also handled correctly for Turkish.  That is, for `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, there is rarely a need for using regexps to get words correctly compared.

(No need for any PHP code.)

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

That reference also points out that `Ş` and `ş` are like a letter between `s` and `t`.  Etc.

If your goal is to *locate* rows with `ı` and `İ`, please elaborate.  This may involve `HEX()` or `utf8_bin`.